# Android : uploaded .apk file to server but cant download that .apk file

Tags: android

I have uploaded my application's .apk file to a server.
When i try to download that .apk file to my android HTC HERO phone then it gives error saying
"file size cannot be determined".

I also enabled settings to "allow install of non-Market applications" in my HTC HERO.

Please help me if i am missing somthing .

and is there any signing we have to do in android like symbian signing in Symbian Devices???

Comment: can you tell me how to deploy .apk file on server ? and on which server I can deploy ? Or give me some useful link for it .

Answer (score 2):

make sure that your mime type setting is properly set on server. i might not allow you to download it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should sign your apps. Check links below.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

http://tordtech.blogspot.com/2009/10/signing-android-applications.html

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/40859.aspx

Good Luck!